# Images are not loading in live server, which was working fine in local server

Tags: php, jquery, yii

My images in site was show correctly in local server but not showing in live server. I'm calling the same image in some other section and was showing correcly. My site url is [pigatu.co.tz](http://pigatu.co.tz).

Comment: I can access the image through URL, but not showing image. showing error as 403. I cleared cache and cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open Firebug while your page is loading, you'll see that for all the images you get a 403 Forbidden.

You have to update the .htaccess or apache configuration from the subdomain on which you are hosting your images to allow files to be server on your main domain.

Comment: I can access the through URL.

Comment: Yeah, It was the config issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi try clearing your cache and cookies. First then follow the below answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable Hotlinking protection on your hosting !

Good luck!

Comment: This was showing correctly in other server : stage.pigatu.co.tz